# Ubuntu stuck on Black Loading Screen

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, reboot, syslinux

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.
After the update when I'm trying to reboot, after restarting it is stuck on the page saying:

*systemd-rfkill.service*

[ OK  ] *Finished* **Load/Dave Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Not actually. I had upgraded from Ubuntu 18.

Comment: After that I'm continuously getting this error while bootup. But if I go to the recovery mode and then continue normal bootup, it opens correctly